# How Do I Merge DFs with a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my code. What I want to do is merge the spread and total values for each week that I have saved in separate files. It works perfectly for individual weeks, but doesn't when I introduce the for loop. I assume its overwriting each time it merges, but when I place the .merge code outside the for loop, it only writes the last iteration to the excel file.

```
year = 2015
weeks = np.arange(1,18)
for week in weeks:

    odds = pd.read_excel(fr'C:\Users\logan\Desktop\Gambling_Scraper\Odds_{year}\Odds{year}Wk{week}.xlsx')
    odds['Favorite'] = odds['Favorite'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('at '))
    odds['Underdog'] = odds['Underdog'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('at '))
    odds['UD_Spread'] = odds['Spread'] * -1

    #new df to add spread
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(odds['Favorite'].append(odds['Underdog']))
    new_df['Tm'] = new_df
    new_df['Wk'] = new_df['Tm'] + str(week)
    new_df['Spread'] = odds['Spread'].append(odds['UD_Spread'])

    #new df to add total
    total_df = pd.DataFrame(odds['Favorite'].append(odds['Underdog']))
    total_df['Tm'] = total_df
    total_df['Wk'] = total_df['Tm'] + str(week)
    total_df['Total']= pd.DataFrame(odds['Total'].append(odds['Total']))


    df['Week'] = df['Week'].astype(int)
    df['Merge'] = df['Tm'].astype(str) + df['Week'].astype(str)


    df =  df.merge(new_df['Spread'], left_on='Merge', right_on=new_df['Wk'], how='left')
    df =  df.merge(total_df['Total'], left_on='Merge', right_on=total_df['Wk'], how='left')
    df['Implied Tm Pts'] = df['Total'].astype(float) /2 - df['Spread'].astype(float)/2
    df.to_excel('DFS2015.xlsx')
```

What I get:

```
Name    Position    Week    Tm  Merge   Spread  Total   Implied Tm Pts
Devonta Freeman RB      1   Falcons Falcons1    3   55  26
Devonta Freeman RB      2   Falcons Falcons2            
Devonta Freeman RB      3   Falcons Falcons3            
Devonta Freeman RB      4   Falcons Falcons4            
Devonta Freeman RB      5   Falcons Falcons5            
Devonta Freeman RB      6   Falcons Falcons6            
Devonta Freeman RB      7   Falcons Falcons7            
Devonta Freeman RB      8   Falcons Falcons8            
Devonta Freeman RB      9   Falcons Falcons9            
Devonta Freeman RB      11  Falcons Falcons11           
Devonta Freeman RB      13  Falcons Falcons13           
Devonta Freeman RB      14  Falcons Falcons14           
Devonta Freeman RB      15  Falcons Falcons15           
Devonta Freeman RB      16  Falcons Falcons16           
Devonta Freeman RB      17  Falcons Falcons17   
Antonio Brown   WR      1   Steelers    Steelers1   7   51  22
```

But I need a value in each row.

Trying to merge 'Spread' and Total from this data:

```
Date    Favorite    Spread  Underdog    Spread2 Total   Away Money 
Line    Home Money Line Week    Favs    Spread  Uds Spread2
September 10, 2015 8:30 PM  Patriots    -7.0    Steelers    7   51.0    +270    -340    1   Patriots1   -7.0    Steelers1   7
September 13, 2015 1:00 PM  Packers -6.0    Bears   6   48.0    -286    +230    1   Packers1    -6.0    Bears1  6
September 13, 2015 1:00 PM  Chiefs  -1.0    Texans  1   40.0    -115    -105    1   Chiefs1 -1.0    Texans1 1
September 13, 2015 1:00 PM  Jets    -4.0    Browns  4   40.0    +170    -190    1   Jets1   -4.0    Browns1 4
September 13, 2015 1:00 PM  Colts   -1.0    Bills   1   44.0    -115    -105    1   Colts1  -1.0    Bills1  1
September 13, 2015 1:00 PM  Dolphins    -4.0    Football Team   4   46.0    -210    +175    1   Dolphins1   -4.0    Football Team1  4
September 13, 2015 1:00 PM  Panthers    -3.0    Jaguars 3   41.0    -150    +130    1   Panthers1   -3.0    Jaguars1    3
September 13, 2015 1:00 PM  Seahawks    -4.0    Rams    4   42.0    -185    +160    1   Seahawks1   -4.0    Rams1   4
September 13, 2015 4:05 PM  Cardinals   -2.0    Saints  2   49.0    +120    -140    1   Cardinals1  -2.0    Saints1 2
September 13, 2015 4:05 PM  Chargers    -4.0    Lions   4   46.0    +160    -180    1   Chargers1   -4.0    Lions1  4
September 13, 2015 4:25 PM  Buccaneers  -3.0    Titans  3   40.0    +130    -150    1   Buccaneers1 -3.0    Titans1 3
September 13, 2015 4:25 PM  Bengals -3.0    Raiders 3   43.0    -154    +130    1   Bengals1    -3.0    Raiders1    3
September 13, 2015 4:25 PM  Broncos -4.0    Ravens  4   46.0    +180    -220    1   Broncos1    -4.0    Ravens1 4
September 13, 2015 8:30 PM  Cowboys -7.0    Giants  7   52.0    +240    -300    1   Cowboys1    -7.0    Giants1 7
September 14, 2015 7:10 PM  Eagles  -3.0    Falcons 3   55.0    -188    +150    1   Eagles1 -3.0    Falcons1    3
September 14, 2015 10:20 PM Vikings -2.0    49ers   2   42.0    -142    +120    1   Vikings1    -2.0    49ers1  2
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the original dataframe, I don't have such imagination. Is it one, and only one, file per week?

Comment: I believe I added it. Is that what you're looking for? And yes, its one file per week.